# Cannot access EC2 via HTTP/HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I recently had to completely rebuild my AWS EC2 environment, because I accidentally deleted the SSH key, thinking it was something else.  Unfortunately, I cannot access my Tomcat instance which I have confirmed is running on that EC2 instance.

I have added the following security groups for inbound HTTP traffic:

```
Type.            Protocol  Port Range       Source
HTTP             TCP       80               0.0.0.0/0
HTTP             TCP       80               ::/0
Custom TCP Rule  TCP       8080             0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule  TCP       8080             ::/0
SSH              TCP       22               (my IP address)
```

I have three security groups, and the above rules were added to the group named `default`:

```
rds-launch-wizard
launch-wizard-1
**default
```

I purchased a domain via AWS which I have pointed to this EC2 instance using Route 53.  Previously, the DNS was available, but now it is not.  However, there is a bigger fundamental problem here because I can't even ping the public IP of my EC2 instance.

I am in fact able to access my EC2 instance via SSH on port 22, which is why I was able to setup Java and Tomcat (both of which I have confirmed are running).

I *suspect* that some state from my previous configuration is responsible for this problem, but I don't even know where to begin looking for something.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Previously, the DNS was available, but now it is not."..Do you mean route53 is not resolving the address to the right IP?

Comment: @PrasadK There may be a problem with Route 53, but I can't even ping my standalone EC2 instance.  Once I get past this, I hope that I can resolve any Route 53 issues which also might be there.

Comment: @PrasadK Are the rules added to security groups cumulative?  That is, does it matter to which group I add the above rules?

Comment: I think you will find the answer to that here - https://serverfault.com/questions/483938/multiple-ec2-security-groups-permissive-or-restrictive

Comment: In the future if you delete an ssh key, do this: 1) Take a snapshot of the root volume using the AWS Console 2) Create a volume for that snapshot 3) Boot a new instance 4) Attache the new volume to it. 5) Mount the volume into a directory like /data 6) Put your ssh key back (or a new one) 7) unmount the volume 8) Shutdown the instance 9) Detach the volume 10) Detach the root volume 11) Attach the volume as the new root volume 12) Boot the instance.

Comment: @Paulpro That's good advice, but in my case I was just testing a Tomcat deployment, so I didn't need to save anything.  I'm not worried about the loss, I'm worried about not being able to get it running again.

Comment: So your Tomcat server is listening on port 8080? Can you telnet to that port? Is it possible that you have an iptables rule that is blocking connections to that port?

Comment: Yes, I can telnet to localhost directly from the instance.  Tomcat is running.  Anyway, I can't even ping the IP address.

Comment: Well you can ssh, so there is connectivity to the instance. Ping might not be working if ICMP is blocked explicitly on your instance. Can you take a look at this - https://askubuntu.com/questions/637470/how-to-check-if-icmp-blocking-is-enabled-in-a-system and share the results in your case?

Comment: @PrasadK I just added a wide open ICMP rule, and I still cannot ping my instance from my local computer.  Pinging works directly from the instance.  I feel that something is blocking/overriding my rules.  No idea what though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have inbound/outbound internet access to your EC2, you need to look for three things:

1. Are you able to SSH from outside or inside AWS via an internet gateway (IGW)?  If you can SSH from outside then you already have IGW setup properly.  Otherwise, make sure your subnet's route table points to IGW by having a route like below:

`0.0.0.0/0 igw-efxxxxxxx    Active No`

2. Network ACL: Go to your EC2's subnet and find its associated NACL
   Create both inbound and outbound rules to ALLOW traffic to the above NACL by adding a rule like below:

`100 ALL Traffic ALL ALL 0.0.0.0/0 ALLOW`

3. Security Groups: Your security groups look good.  No changes required there.  *However*, based on the comments you made below it appears that, while you did define a security group with the proper inbound rules, for whatever reason you did not associate that security group with your EC2 instance.  As a result, the inbound rules you defined were not being applied.  To fix this, from the EC2 instance tag access the following:

`Actions -> Networking -> Change Security Groups`

Then, associate your security group with your instance by checking the appropriate box.  After making these changes, your inbound rules should take effect, and you should be able to hit your Tomcat instance running on EC2.

Comment: Hi Raj, for #2 I checked the VPC tab, where I see three subnets.  All of them have ALL Traffic enabled for inbound and outbound traffic.  For #1 and #3, yes I can SSH and my security groups are the same I was using previously.

Comment: Go to another EC2 and try to ping and curl (HTTP) and see if both are accessible from within AWS. If not successful, then the problem is inside the EC2 (internal iptables/firewall etc.). If successful then the issue is IGW/NACL/Subnet. You can launch another nano EC2 with same settings just for testing purposes, then terminate.

Comment: I only have a single EC2 instance (I removed the previous one because I could not access it).  If the problem be IP tables or a firewall, where would I go to fix that?

Comment: Instead of going to the VPC tab, go to EC2, click on Description tab and copy the associated subnet. Then go to VPC tab, click on subnets and search for the copied subnet. This is important because sometimes you accidentally look at a VPC in a different region

Comment: Yes, there is a subnet entry in the VPC tab corresponding to my EC2 instance.  The network ACL settings look open and good, but what about the route table, does that matter?

Comment: Raj, I just found something which has a smell.  From the EC2 tab, when I click on the `view inbound rules` link from the description on the bottom, I see only a single rule for port 22 allowing all TCP traffic.  I suggest that maybe my inbound rules are not being applied.

Comment: The other security groups were not being applied for some reason.  I will investigate this and then post an answer later.

Comment: Looks like you have only the launch wizard security group attached to your instance.Go to EC2 page, select EC2 choose menu Actions/Networking/Change Security Groups. There you will find what security groups are attached to your instance and you can also Assign Security groups to your running instance. No need to stop/start or reboot. The the security group rules immediately apply to your EC2.